# How to use JavaScript or jQuery to trim dynamic URL from absolute to relative

Tags: javascript, jquery

The system I'm using occasionally adds the full path to the src of a dynamic img.

```
<a href="#" class="link">
    <img src="http://www.domain.com/images/wish-add.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

I need everything before /images to to be removed.

I need be able to do it without manually referencing the domain. The domain is not always going to be the same.

I can remove parts that are always the same.. Like /images.. but I don't know how to remove anything before /images regardless of what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('img').attr('src', function (i, src) {
    return src.replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/, '');
});
```

Comment: That worked a treat! I'll have to read up - I don't fully understand it.